Docker inside Jenkins Container running in EKS
I'm running a jenkins container in EKS and everything is working fine except when one of the pipelines has to build docker images.
I've installed docker cli on my image but when i shell into the jenkins pod and run docker ps or docker version, i get the following error:
jenkins@b8b3fe3f061d:/$ docker ps
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
jenkins@b8b3fe3f061d:/$ docker version
Client:
 Version:           18.09.2
 API version:       1.39
 Go version:        go1.10.6
 Git commit:        6247962
 Built:             Sun Feb 10 04:13:52 2019
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

My Dockerfile is below:
FROM jenkins/jenkins:2.440.1-lts
# Pipelines with Blue Ocean UI and Kubernetes
ARG DOCKER_GID=999
RUN jenkins-plugin-cli --plugins blueocean kubernetes
USER root
COPY java-17-amazon-corretto-jdk_17.0.8.8-1_amd64.deb ./
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl vim zip unzip java-common wget libltdl7 \
    && dpkg --install java-17-amazon-corretto-jdk_17.0.8.8-1_amd64.deb \
    && rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh

USER jenkins
RUN curl -s https://get.sdkman.io | bash \
    && chmod a+x "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh" \
    && source "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"

ENV JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-amazon-corretto/
ENV PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-amazon-corretto/:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
RUN mkdir -p /var/jenkins_home/.ssh \
    && mkdir -p /var/jenkins_home/.gradle \
    && mkdir -p /var/jenkins_home/.aws \
    && chmod 0700 /var/jenkins_home/.ssh \
    && chmod -R 755 /var/jenkins_home \
    && chown -R 1000:1000 /var/jenkins_home 
ADD id_rsa /var/jenkins_home/.ssh/
ADD credentials /var/jenkins_home/.aws
ADD known_hosts /var/jenkins_home/.ssh/
ADD gradle.properties /var/jenkins_home/.gradle/

USER root
EXPOSE 22
RUN chmod -R 0700 /var/jenkins_home/.ssh \
    && chmod 0600 /var/jenkins_home/.ssh/id_rsa \
    && chmod 0600 /var/jenkins_home/.ssh/known_hosts \
    && chmod 644 /var/jenkins_home/.aws/credentials
# Install Docker
RUN wget -q -O /tmp/docker-cli.deb https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/dists/stretch/pool/stable/amd64/docker-ce-cli_18.09.2~3-0~debian-stretch_amd64.deb \
    && dpkg -i /tmp/docker-cli.deb

# create docker group, add jenkins user to it
RUN groupadd -g $DOCKER_GID docker \
    && usermod -aG docker jenkins

USER jenkins


I'm not familiar with EKS, but the root issue is the container cannot access the host machine's docker socket. When containerized Jenkins runs a docker command, it's actually communicating with the host machine's docker daemon. How was the Jenkins container started? Do you have control over the volume mounts?

It works on my minikube cluster but when i try the same on EC2, it doesn't work. I do have volume mounted in the container from EC2.
    volume {
      name = "dockersock"
      host_path {
        path = "/var/run/docker.sock"
        type = "Socket"
      }
    }

volume_mount {
name       = "dockersock"
mount_path = "/var/run/docker.sock"
}
